# Is there a way to recursively await a value in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, es6-promise

I am making a project with Javascript, and I have an object that has a getter that returns promises. This object can me mocked with this code:

```js
async function asyncifiedObject(object) {
  let o = {};

  let keys = [...Object.keys(object)];
  for (let item of keys) {
    o.__defineGetter__(item, async () => {
      if (object && object[item]) {
        if (typeof object[item] == "object") {
          // Do other async things, like network requests, etc.
          return await asyncifiedObject(object[item]);
        } else {
          return object[item];
        }
      }
    });
  }
  return o;
}
```

I get one of these objects like this:

```js
let o=asyncifiedObject({hello:{world:{it:{is:{nice:{out:"today"}}}}}})
```

When I go to access on of the proprieties on the object, I currently am doing `await (await (await (await (await (await (await o).hello).world).it).is).nice).out`, but that is long and looks horrible.

I could use a function to do it like `await getAsyncValues(o,"hello","world","it","is","nice","out")`, but what I would like to do is something like `await o.hello.world.it.is.nice.out`, and that doesn't work because all the promises need to be awaited, not just the first one. Is there any way that could work?

By the way, here's a sample implementation of `getAsyncValues`:

```js
async function getAsyncValues(object,...values){
  let r=object;
  for(let value of values){
    r=(await r)[value]
  }
  return r
}
```

Comment: `__defineGetter__`, really? Also there's no point in using spread syntax around `Object.keys`.

Comment: "*I have an object that has a getter that returns promises*" - since you say that `asyncifiedObject` is only a mock, what does your real object look like?

Comment: The spread syntax is something needed in my actual implementation that I was too lazy to remove, and my real object either gets the data from the underlying object, or fetches it from another server, hence me needing to do this at all. Also, what's wrong with `__defineGetter__`?

Comment: `asyncifiedObject` does have the same semantics as my real object though.

Comment: `__defineGetter__` is deprecated since ages. Use [`Object.defineProprty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) instead

Comment: Ok, thank you for the tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way to make this work exactly the way I wanted! The await statement, donsn't just work with promises. It works with thenables too. A thenable is an object with a Promise-like then method. I modified `getAsyncValues`, and the final code is below.

```js
(async () => {
  async function asyncifiedObject(object) {
    let o = {};

    let keys = [...Object.keys(object)];
    for (let item of keys) {
      o.__defineGetter__(item, async () => {
        if (object && object[item]) {
          if (typeof object[item] == "object") {
            // Do other async things, like network requests, etc.
            return thenableHack(await asyncifiedObject(object[item]));
          } else {
            return object[item];
          }
        }
      });
    }
    return o;
  }

  function thenableHack(object, ...values) {
    let o = {
      then: async e => {
        let r = object;
        for (let value of values) {
          r = (await r)[value];
        }
        e(r);
      },
      catch: () => {}
    };
    return new Proxy(o, {
      get: (o, p) => {
        return o[p] || thenableHack(object, ...values, p);
      }
    });
  }

  let o = thenableHack(
    asyncifiedObject({
      hello: { world: { it: { is: { nice: { out: "today" } } } } }
    })
  );
  console.log(await o.hello.world.it.is.nice.out);
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

That's an interesting situation. No, there's nothing syntactic to help you here, you'll need to use your function or similar.